# Using only one particular library constant

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <complex.h>
```

`M_PI` links so many definitions while using above libraries.

```c
c-std.h /usr/include/kpathsea
| #define M_PI 3.14159265358979323846

mathematics.h /usr/includefibavutil

| #define M_PI 3.14159265358979323846 /* pi */

math.h fusrfinclude

| define M_PI 3.14159265358979323846 /* pi */

defines.h /usrfinclude/ngspice

| #define M_PI CONSTpi

missing.h /usrfinclude/ruby-2.7.0/ruby

| define M_PI 3.14159265358979323846

math.h /usrfinclude/wx-3.0/wx

| #define M_PI 3.1415926535897932384626433832795
```

How can I specify belong `M_PI` only one library because `VS Code` gives an error `identifier "M_PI" is undefined`

```objectivec
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <complex.h>
#include "convert.h"

int main()
{   
    

    int desire=1;
    int wind[desire];
    for (int i = 0; i < desire; i++)
    {
    printf("\nEnter degree of wind:");
    scanf("%d",&wind[i]);
    wind[i]=convert(wind[i]);
    }
    
    double complex sum=0;
    double a=(M_PI/3);
    double test=cos(a);

    printf("\n%f\n",test);
    for (int i = 0; i < desire; i++)
    {
        sum+=cos(wind[i])+ sin(wind[i]) * I;
    }


    printf("\n%d minutes average wind:%.2f %.2fi",desire,creal(sum),cimag(sum));
    double r =hypot(creal(sum),cimag(sum));
    double angle= convert(atanf(creal(sum)/cimag(sum))) ;

    


    return 0;
}
```

Convert function's definition

```objectivec
#include <math.h>
#include "convert.h"
double convert(double radian) {
    
        return(radian * (180/M_PI));
    }
```

Comment: What is your compiler?

Comment: Code-OSS (VS Code)

Comment: is it the compiler or intellisence?

Comment: I use gcc configuration in intellisense

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I added the whole test because it's tiny.